# Set of finite partitions of the unit interval

Tags: compactness, set-partition

Is the set of partitions of a given length, say $n$, of the unit interval compact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subsequently realized that it is not compact.

First of all, let us think of a partition of length $n$ as a vector of length $n$ with given endpoints: $0$ and $1$. Therefore a partition is a vector of length $n-2$, of points chosen from $(0,1)$, ordered from lowest to highest. Therefore the set of all such partitions, $S \subset (0,1)^{n-2}$, is bounded.

But it is not closed because it is easy to show that there exist sequences of such partitions which collapse on to $(0,0,...,1,1)$ in the limit, which is a degenerate partition (i.e. not a partition of length $n$). For example, suppose $n$ is even and consider the sequence of partitions $\{(\frac{1}{N},\frac{2}{N},...,\frac{(n-2)}{2N},\frac{N-\frac{n-2}{2}}{N},...,\frac{(N-2)}{N},\frac{(N-1)}{N})\}^{\infty}_{N=10}$, which collapses on to $(0,0,...,1,1)$ in the limit. Similarly it is easy to show for odd $n$ as well.

However, following the above logic, the set of all finite partitions of $[0,1]$ *upto* length $n$ is a compact set.

Comment: I think we're missing some details here. It seems that you have in mind a topology, and in fact a metric, on the set of partitions; can you define it? Are you only interested in partitions whose elements are subintervals of the unit interval? Is it the closed unit interval rather than the open one? Do you include $\{\{0\}, (0, 1]\}$ as a partition? What is the distance between $\{[0, 1/2], (1/2, 1]\}$ and $\{[0, 1/2), [1/2, 1]\}$?